# WP Query returning all posts when Meta_query is null

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I have a situation here where we have two input fields, one is searching by custom meta fields (ACF) the second is a free search.
the client is asking me for results to display in an OR fashion.

If `meta_query = null`, the query runs ignoring this parameter. this is expected. what I need is when `meta_query = null`, the `WP_Query` to return no results, not all of them.

I tried using relation `OR` to compare arrays between the meta query and the search, this did not work (but would be my preferred method).
I managed to get things working as below, however, `meta_query` when its null returns all posts from my custom post type. removing other parameters just means its defaults back to standard posts, etc. my solution as shown here is kinda crazy. I do not think I can put that into production.. can someone please help?

Basically I need both the free search and the `meta_query` to not return any posts if their values are `null` or empty.

Thanks.

```php
/*
   Generating final WP_Query
*/    
if (empty($_REQUEST['cboSearchKeyword'])) {
$args_meta = [
   'post_type' => 'iamnotarealpostype',
   'posts_per_page'    => '0',
   'orderby' => 'date',
   'order' => 'DESC', 
   'meta_query' => $meta_qry,
   ];
   echo ("<h1>empty meta</h1>");
}
   else {
   $args_meta = [
   'post_type'     => 'toolkit',
   'posts_per_page'    => '15',
   'orderby' => 'date',
   'order' => 'DESC', 
   'meta_query' => $meta_qry,
   ];
}

if (empty($_REQUEST['tool-text'])){

$args_search = [
   'post_type' => 'iamnotarealpostype',
   'posts_per_page'    => '15',
   'orderby' => 'date',
   'order' => 'DESC',  
   's' => (isset($_REQUEST['tool-text']))?$_REQUEST['tool-text']:'', 
   //'tax_query' => $terms,
   ];
}
else {

$args_search = [
   'post_type'     => 'toolkit',
   'posts_per_page'    => '15',
   'orderby' => 'date',
   'order' => 'DESC',  
   's' => (isset($_REQUEST['tool-text']))?$_REQUEST['tool-text']:'', 
   //'tax_query' => $terms,
   ];
}

$query_one = new WP_Query($args_meta);
$query_two = new WP_Query($args_search);


$merged_items->posts = array_merge( $query_one->posts, $query_two->posts );

$merged_items->post_count = $query_one->post_count + $query_two->post_count;

foreach($merged_items->posts as $post) : 
setup_postdata( $post );
```

Comment: you've missed out the most important part of your question, the value of `$meta_qry` and how it's set. Can you fix the indentation? I tried to edit your question to include paragraphs and improve readability but there's not enough context on your question to fully process what's going on

Comment: Hi Tom. you have asked me before about indentation, I hope I have fixed it. The meta_qry values come from a user input, which is either tags or a checkbox for the values, and are therefore NULL when no input is given. thats the key issue- if NULL values are in the query for meta_query, the query outputs all posts from the selected post type- which you would expect to happen of course. This is the reason when its NULL I have applied this dummy post type to the queries. - but surely there is a better way of handling this? Thanks.

Comment: can you include the code that generates `$meta_qry`? If you're saying that it's a string inputted by the user then that would be incorrect, but it's critical to your question and has been left out. Any answer that's written would directly impact the code that controls `$meta_qry` so you need to include it, a textual description isn't enough. If you're refusing to do this you should explicitly say so and why rather than ignoring the request

Comment: Tom I'm sorry it think you are being deliberately difficult. The meta ary being null is the issue I dunno imagine something if you need it.

Comment: im flagging mods comments as unkind. there is no reason to demand this. the point is in fact, if the meta_query itsnt there- thats why i havent added anything. if its null or whatever, the query defaults to showing everyitning in that post type. i need a hand to have the inverse condition, not clear on the bst way. thanks.

Comment: $meta_qry = null;

Comment: It's your choice not to provide it but I wouldn't  edit complaints into your question as it will put off other people who could answer. I requested it because without it the answer would be inferior with a high chance it wouldn't fix your problem. I've edited out the complaints and I'm going to lock comments now as they've become un-constructive. Remember, everyone here who comments and answers is unpaid and chooses to volunteer their time.